# macOS shell script to stop and run apache and mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, shell, terminal

I've asked already this but someone decided that the question had already an answer without understood really what I need. 
The old question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007477/start-mysql-8-0-16-and-embed-macos-apache-server-from-terminal-script)
I want to make a script that I can run from the terminal of osx to start apache and mysql using the start command and then when I finished with them, I want to use the stop command or something similar to stop and quit from them. 
I don't have experience with shell scripting, will be this possible? can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is installed on MacOS as a launch daemon.

Here's the shell command to start and stop it:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/8.0/en/osx-installation-launchd.html for more on the MySQL Launch Daemon.

An alternative way to install MySQL on MacOS is with `brew`. Then the usage to start and stop it is done with supervisord. Here's the way to start and stop a service managed by supervisord:

```
supervisorctl start mysql

supervisorctl stop mysql
```

Comment: I'm using this command for now that was posted inside another question. `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` to start mysql. I want to avoid to launch it when the mac is started, this is why I want to create a simple script that will start my development envoirment automatically when i run it